# Checking input passivity with any function?

Tags: dynamical-systems, control-theory, stability-theory

Given a nonlinear function with input $u \in \mathbb{R}^n$, time $t \geq 0$ and output $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ as

$$
y = h(u, t)
$$

I have read (in Nonlinear Systems by H. Khalil, chapter 6.1) that such a function is input feedforward passive if $u^T y \geq u^T \phi(u)$ for some function $\phi$.

While there the general case is considered that $h$ can be time varying I am only interested in the more special case that $h$ is a function of $u$ only. An example for such a $h$ could be a saturation function.

What I now don't get is: Why are there no further restrictions on the function $\phi$? Can I really pick *any* function I can think of (e.g. discontinous/constant/periodic/etc.), as long as the inequality holds?

I couldn't find any restrictions on $\phi$ in the textbook, but maybe the author just didn't list them?

Because can't I just always pick $\phi = h$? Then I would get $u^T \phi(u) = u^T h(u) = u^T y$ which is obviously $\geq u^T y$ since it is equal. So to me, without additional constraints on $\phi$, this definition seems pointless because every $h$ would then be input feedforward passive.

**Question**: Can I really pick any $\phi$ to check input feedforward passivity?

Comment: Can you give some reference to your definitions? At first glance, it does not make sense to have a physical system in which the control input directly affects the output.

Comment: @MachineLearner The reference is "Nonlinear Systems" by H. Khalil, chapter 6 (Passivity). There is the section 6.1 (Memoryless functions). For example, $f$ might represent a saturation function.

Comment: Now, I get what you mean. Didn't Khalil use another variable for the input? Something like $\xi$ or $\zeta$? The $u$ just confused me. You should also consider adding the relevant sections from the book.

Comment: @MachineLearner No, it is almost the same as here, just that he called the function $h$ instead of $f$. I changed that and also updated the question with more information.

Comment: @MachineLearner I also found these lecture notes online, where on slide 7 the same definition is used but also without any constraints on $\phi$: http://ele.aut.ac.ir/~abdollahi/Lec_6_N11.pdf

Answer (score 0):

The key inequality for the passivity of memoryless functions is that $u^\top \phi(u)\ge 0$. This gives you constraints for the function $\phi(u)$.

Comment: But I mean input-feedforward passivity, not "normal" passivity. I thought a bit more about it and I think that one can actually take $\phi = h$... Especially, since the inequality you posted is fullfilled with that choice of $\phi$. However that wont lead to anything useful, because to maintain the original behavior, the feedforward of $\phi$ in the feedback loop has to be compensated by a feedback of $\phi$ in the feedforward, so we would end up with the same system...

Comment: I think the problem with my understanding of the definition is that every function can be trivially made passive by input-feedforward, namely just by input-feedforwarding the function itself, times negative one. That gives obviously zero, so a passive operator. So it is not really an intrinsic property of the memoryless function itself. Because of that it still seems to me the definition of input-feedforward passivity for memoryless function is somehow pointless

Comment: You are right. If we consider the input-feedforward passivity, then any time-invariant memoryless output $y=h(u)$ is input-feedforward passive, as you said. The limitation is that it is not always possible (and reasonable) to implement such a feedforward.